# bootstrap tabs to accordion active is not working on web to mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

```
bootstrap tabs to accordion i doing.
1.above 768px tab showing, tab active working (green color).
2.below 767px accordion showing, accordion working but active color not work.
```

[URL: jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txm1rwbz/2/)

Comment: Your English makes no sense. Please expand upon your explanation and also post your code **here as a working snippet**

Comment: can you describe you problem better? the provided link shows a working accordion.